# USB Linux Device Driver

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm  trying to learn Unix kernel development and I'm asked to "play around with the usb driver code and learn things".
where should I start?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I advice you to begin reading this [USB device driver](https://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch13.pdf) document to understand basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should start with learning USB protocol first and then analysing usb linux drivers. Read the usb specifications from www.usb.org.

Answer (score 3):

First go through basics of USB

Try to understand USB document from free electronic website

After that go to Linux kernel document

Continuously try to go through Linux kernel codes in USB module and corelate with document contains.

If any board is available then try to put debugs in kernel code, dump to board and observe the code flow for different USB devices.